# SQLAlchemy search on ts_vector column without to_tsvector

Tags: postgresql, search, sqlalchemy

I have a computed column that is a `tsvector`.

The api sends a search query, but, of course, these are not valid `tsvector`s. Postgres's `plainto_tsquery` converts text input to a correctly formatted `tsvector` for matching.

This breaks with SQLAlchemy.

`column.match(func.plainto_tsquery('english', search))` does not work because SQLAlchemy converts that to:

```
column @@ to_tsquery(plainto_tsquery('english', 'the search query'))
```

what I actually want is the correct operator (`@@`) but without the magic conversion

```
column @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'the search query')
```

A dumb way that works but is not what I want is:

```
column.match(
  cast(func.plainto_tsquery('english', search), String)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
column.op("@@")(func.plainto_tsquery('english', search))
```